# Type annotation for subclass factory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've recently started migrating codebase of one of projects of my company to TypeScript and i struggle with type annotations to this code:

```
function factory( Base ) {
  return class Extended extends Base {
    ...
  }
}

const Extended = factory( React.Component );
const PureExtended = factory( React.PureComponent );
```

What i try to describe with TypeScript:

- factory accepts only classes that inherit from React.Component class.
- factory returns class that inherits from React.Component class.

What i tried:

```
function factory( Base: React.Component<P, S> ): React.Component<P, S> {
  return class Extended extends Base {
    ...
  }
}

const Extended = factory( React.Component );
const PureExtended = factory( React.PureComponent );
```

This fails horribly on typechecking.

Im using:

- TypeScript 2.5.2
- Visual Studio Code 1.16.1
- @types/react 16.0.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that i managed to get it to work with this:

```
type RCConstructor<P, S> = new(...args: any[]) => React.Component<P, S>;

function factory<T extends RCConstructor<{}, {}>> ( Base: T ) {
  return class Extended extends Base {
    /* Extended implementation */
  };
}

export const Extended = factory( React.Component );
export const PureExtended = factory( React.PureComponent );
```

The solution comes from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html. It's pretty obvious from documentation what is going on here. The real question now is "Why is https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html not covering this?".

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the article you've linked to in your answer what you need to make mixin work is `Constructor` type. Optionally you can constrain classes that can be extended by providing specific type to `Constructor`.

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function factory<T extends Constructor<React.Component>> ( Base: T ) {
  return class Extended extends Base {
    /* Extended implementation */
  };
}

export const Extended = factory( React.Component );
export const PureExtended = factory( React.PureComponent );
```